# Missing .dll error reoccurence

Tags: visual-c++

I have a question regarding VC++ 5.0.

For a dialog-based project I am writing, I have linked it to a particular dynamic link library called `File32.dll` by adding the corresponding `.lib` file to my project debug folder as you do.

I also linked to this library in the Project Settings. This library contains functions specific to a particular application which I need to access. All of the necessary header files have been included and the project builds without errors or warnings.

The problem is that once I try to debug and run the dialog, an error appears:

> The program can't start because `OUTPUT.dll` is missing from your
>   computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

`OUTPUT.dll` is a library I am not linking to for this project. And when I add this particular `.dll` to my debug folder, the same error appears with a different `.dll` (`SYSINT32.dll`).

No matter how much I add these dlls to my debug folder, the error message reappears with a new dll. Bare in mind, the project debugged and ran successfully before I linked to `File32.lib`. So I feel that the problem lies with File32.lib. Any ideas on what might be happening with the linker?

Comment: Instead of trial and error, please get Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com) and drop your DLL into that program.  It will tell you exactly what DLL's are required at program load time.

Comment: Dude, Visual Studio 5.0 is _eighteen years old_. It was released in 1997. It predates even Visual Studio 6.0, which has been retconned out of the C++ continuity. It's possibly older than _you_ are! What on earth are you doing with such antiquated "technology"?

Comment: In fact, I'm untagging C++, because C++ (what we mean by that term today) didn't even exist at the time.

Comment: Well according to my supervisor it better suits company software...don't ask me man...I have the deal with the bloody thing as I'm just a grunt... I use Visual Studio 2012 too but there was licensing issues ...I know its BS right?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to open your `File32.dll`. It will show all DLLs this one (statically) depends on. It will also highlight the missing ones.

---

As for [VC++ 5.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B) ... I feel the need to comment ...

> Visual C++ 5.0, which included MFC 4.21 and was released 1997-04-28 (...)

that's an amazing 18 years :-)

Comment: Yeah my company uses very outdated software haha...Thx mate! Although its old, I prefer it to Visual Studio... I just like the old windows 98 -esque grey panel interface

Comment: Please note that VC++ 5.0 is a pre-ANSI standard compiler.  Most modern day C++ libraries and source code do not support VC 5.0.  The C++ language has changed a lot since 1997, and that compiler will fail to compile a lot of the C++ code that's out there now.

Comment: I'm surprised it even works: those old MFC versions were not compatible with DEP, which is present in all Windows versions still supported.

Comment: It's not just old; it's _ludicrously_ old.

Comment: @R2Delta: You should resign in protest. There is no place for such nonsense in any company!

Comment: Problem is, my supervisor is a dinosaur when it comes to software ....... I'm gonna upgrade to Visual Studio after this project...bout time too